# Trying to aggregate Queried data using a forloop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am having a little bit of trouble creating a loop that

1. sqlQueries every device in the variable "sensorname" (this is roughly 30 elements, but will increase in the future)
2. takes the data table associated with the device query and puts it into a separate data frame "data1" but keeps adding into it.

Below is my sample loop and a sample of what data1 looks like which is "correct", but not complete. LSF20_3a0925 is the last element in the variable sensorname so essentially the loop runs 30 times each time overwriting the data in variable data1 until it runs for the last time.

```
library(RODBC)

  ch <- odbcConnect("SweetLab", uid='---', pwd='------')
  sqlQuery(ch, "use SweetDatabase")     
  sensorname <- sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT site_device.code 
                                   FROM site_device, device 
                                   WHERE site_device.did=device.id AND
                                   device.name='LSF20' 
                                   LIMIT 0, 1000;",
                             sep="")
                          )
for(k in 1:length(sensorname[[1]])){
  sqlQuery(ch, "use SweetAnalysis")  
  sql <- na.omit(sqlQuery(ch,paste("select * From ",sensorname[[1]][k],"_Events",sep="")));
  if (is.null(sql))
  {return(NULL)}
  data1 <- merge(sensorname[[1]][k],sql)
}

 #############################################
 data1
       x      row_names PeaksP1Time PeaksP1
 1  LSF20_3a0925    24  1346781683  5.076920
 2  LSF20_3a0925    31  1358444323  0.043240
 3  LSF20_3a0925    13  1358444463  0.133170
 4  LSF20_3a0925    12  1358445120  5.286443
```

Any help would be most appretiated I am new to writing code in general so please excuse me if this is a dumb question. I've searched around for a bit on this topic, but honestly wasn't quite sure how to search for this topic.

Comment: Are you [ZdWhite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14886576/324364)? If so, please don't re-post questions under new accounts.

Comment: i tried to find my question and assumed it didn't get posted correctly. I didn't mean to spam I'll delete the other one as it is incomplete anyway.

Comment: Ok...I flagged the two questions for a moderator to look at, so don't be surprised if these two accounts are merged automatically for you as well. (You won't need to do anything, the mod will take care of it.)

Answer (score 2):

After some tweaking this looks great!

```
    library(RODBC)
     ch <- odbcConnect("SweetLab", uid='***', pwd='******') 
    sqlQuery(ch, "use SweetDatabase")     
    sensorname <- sqlQuery(ch,paste("select site_device.code from site_device, device where site_device.did=device.id and device.name='LSF20' LIMIT 0, 1000;",sep=""));   
    sqlQuery(ch, "use SweetAnalysis") 
    Datalist <- lapply(sensorname[[1]],function(x){
     query <- paste("SELECT PeaksP1Time,PeaksP1  FROM ",x,"_Events",sep="")
     dat <- (na.omit(sqlQuery(ch,query)))
     data2.nlist<-list(device=x,data=dat)
names(Datalist)<-sensorname$code[1:30]     
 })
    close(ch)
```

Looking at the structure of this list I get

```
> str(Datalist[1:3]) 
List of 3
 $ LSF20_39ecf7:List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    306 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ PeaksP1Time: num [1:306] 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 ...
  .. ..$ PeaksP1    : num [1:306] 4.5 4.379 0.706 3 0 ...
 $ LSF20_39cd3e:List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    202 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ PeaksP1Time: num [1:202] 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 ...
  .. ..$ PeaksP1    : num [1:202] 0.664 3.235 5.765 4.636 2.936 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:24] 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:24] "203" "204" "205" "206" ...
 $ LSF20_3a09ac:List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    42 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ PeaksP1Time: num [1:42] 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 1.35e+09 ...
  .. ..$ PeaksP1    : num [1:42] 5.589 2.897 2.713 1.706 0.831 ...
```

Now I'm moving on to the next phase of this which is graphing multiple sets at the same time.

My problem is how do I tell R that it should graph the data with in each list or specific lists. I have a save file of the work history if anyone wants to work with something reproducible.

Comment: Unless you're answering your own question (which is OK), you should add that as a follow-up edit to the question, and give credit to the user(s) who provided the guidance you needed.

Comment: I wasn't totally sure how to do that. I tried upvoting the correct response but it wouldn't allow me, and it only lets me add comments to people who have started a thread under an answer. Sorry I am very new to stack over flow

Comment: Did you know that you can merge your accounts using the following steps: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 0):

Ok..without a reproducible example it is not clear what you asked. here how I would do it..

1. I open the connection
2. I loop using `lapply` to create a list
3. I close the connection
4. I bind list elements into data.frame. I assume taht you have the same columns for different sensor table.

   ```
    ch <- odbcConnect("SweetLab", uid='---', pwd='------')
    ll <- lapply(sensorname[[1]],function(x){
       query <- paste("SELECT *  FROM ",x,"_Events",sep="")
       dat <- na.omit(sqlQuery(ch,query))
       data.frame(sensor=x,dat)
    })
    close(ch)
    data1 <- do.call(rbind,ll)
   ```

Comment: @user1978377 does this answer you need?

Answer (score 0):

This is resource intensive, but will work.

```
# before your for loop
results <- list()

#inside your for loop 
for (k ......) {
  ....
  ....
  results[[k]] <- sql
}


# after your for loop

Data1 <- do.call(rbind, results)   # if same schema
   # OR
Data1 <- do.call(merge, results)   # if different schema
```